# How do invoke script with another node script?

Tags: node.js

I have an node app that runs as a cron job every few seconds:

```
   var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
   new CronJob('*/5 * * * * *', function(){
       console.log('Here invoke a script called requestdata');
   }, null, true, "America/Los_Angeles");
```

and I just want to call a script without invoking functions on it. So its not

```
          requestdata.foo();
```

but just call requestdata in same directory.  how is this done?  If it was on command line I would just do:

```
     node requestdata
```

but how do I do this inside another script?

Comment: Why not actually use Cron for this?  And, you can always execute a child process...

Comment: Well I am planning to use cron for it but the bulk of the code is inside a file called requestdata.js  so I am trying to find out how to call that stuff from within cron function without inline everything into the cron function.

Comment: I don't understand why the location of your script determines what system you should use for executing processes regularly.

Comment: Well lets assume I cannot modify requestdata.js, and make it into a function. I just want to know the correct way to invoke it from within the cron function.

Comment: Why not just use a child process then?  You could also use the VM, load the file and `exec()`, simply `require()` it, etc.  There's plenty you could do, but what you do depends on your specific needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `child_process`, like so

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.fork(__dirname + '/request data.js');
```

See http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: how to pass parameter to that '/request data.js'  script

Answer (score 2):

This solution also shows how to pass parameters to the "request data.js" script

```
var cp = require('child_process');
cp.fork(__dirname + '/request data.js',[array,of,string,prams]);
```